# Tell homebrew never build from source

Tags: macos, homebrew

During package installation via homebrew on macOS, if my network is not stable and one download fails, homebrew will download the source and start building from source. This will take a long time and high CPU usage, which is unwanted. How can I tell homebrew retry or just stop when downloading fails?

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sqlite-3.27.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to homebrew.bintray.com:443 
Error: Failed to download resource "sqlite"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sqlite-3.27.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3270100.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.27.1 --enable-dynamic-extensions --enable-readline --disable-editline
^C
```

Comment: Ask this on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pete how can I move my question there?

Comment: I think only someone with more points than me can move it

Comment: Are you using `--force-bottle` ?

Comment: @RichardBarber `--force-bottle` is meant for Homebrew developers; you shouldn’t use it if you’re not 100% sure of what you’re doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late answer but another way to make it fail without building from source is setting the `HOMEBREW_NO_BOTTLE_SOURCE_FALLBACK` environment variable explained in the [man page](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment), e.g. `export HOMEBREW_NO_BOTTLE_SOURCE_FALLBACK=1`.

I haven't tested it yet, as I found the [solution](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/solved-option-to-not-build-from-source/3858) after I needed it.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work. `HOMEBREW_NO_BOTTLE_SOURCE_FALLBACK=1 brew install gmailctl` still builds from source.

Comment: The related code is [`formula_installer.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/f7c7e2e793ed35f354974f2fcdb5fb22a3d924a3/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb#L311-L313). I cannot debug this code because Homebrew would undo any change (good for normal users, but difficult for developers).

Answer (score 2):

You can `brew fetch --retry <formula>` to retry the fetching if it fails. Once the bottle is fetched, you can `brew install` it.

Combine both commands with:

```
brew fetch --retry <formula> && brew install <formula>
```